# Skip validation inside specific control

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a Users controller with the following validation on the password :

```rb
validates :password, length: {minimum: 3, message: 'is too short, minimum of 3 characters'}, on: [:create, :update]
```

But in another controller, I perform this:

```rb
def create
  user_params = params.require(:user).permit(:email)
  @user = User.find_by_email(user_params[:email])

  if @user
    @user.regenerate_recover_password
    ...
```

And so I get the following error :

```
Validation failed: Password is too short, minimum of 3 characters
```

The basic idea was to have this validation because otherwise it is possible to use an empty password

Any idea ?
Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be approaching the problem wrong - instead of trying to limit your validations per controller use the `if:` and `unless:` options to limit when the password validation is enforced:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :password, 
    length: { 
      minimum: 3, 
      message: 'is too short, minimum of 3 characters' 
    }, 
    confirmation: true,
    if: :password_required?

  private

  def password_required?
    new_record? || reset_token_sent?
  end

  def reset_token_sent?
    # ... @todo implement
  end
end
```

Note that these shouldn't be confused with the `if/unless` Ruby keywords. These are just options passed to the method.

Comment: On a side note - if your a beginner at Rails reinventing the authorization wheel isn't a great idea unless you're doing it as a learning experience. Use a battle tested solution instead like Devise instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, indeed I know it's not a good idea, it's only to test, I prefer to try by myself to understand better before using gems at all without knowing what it does :)

Answer (score 0):

**Save**

Ref: [Rails skip validation within model with save?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923681/rails-skip-validation-within-model-with-save)

```
.save(validate: false)
```

**Update**

You may have to use this inside your function. If you updating instead of saving: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9474881/1006936

```
object.attribute = value
object.save(:validate => false)
```

**Skip validation in function**

To skip update for your function: [skip certain validation method in Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881712/skip-certain-validation-method-in-model)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :password, length: {minimum: 3, message: 'is too short, minimum of 3 characters'}, on: [:create, :update]
, unless: :regenerate_recover_password
....
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand (I'm a Rails beginner) because I don't have a save method in my method. See full method code : https://zupimages.net/up/21/27/is02.png

Something like :
```
@user.recover_password = random_string_gen
@user.save(validate: false)
...
```

Comment: Check now. Added that too.

Comment: it enters an infinite loop and the application crashes with this :/

What I don't understand is that the generated string should pass the validation, if I give it a string manually of 4char or more it's ok